# How to find cpu spike for the past 2 days?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, command-line, cpu, cpu-usage

I was trying to find the linux command to show the cpu spike for the past 2 days.
I was able to get the CPU% with sar command `sar -f /var/log/sa/sa$(date +%d -d "2 days ago")` but it is not displaying any process id or name. I tried sar with pidstat combination `sar -f /var/log/sa/sa$(date +%d -d "2 days ago") | xargs -I{} ps -o pid,comm -p {}` but did not got desired output.

What is the linux command (ubuntu) to find out the cpu spike for the past 2 days.

I cannot use htop or atop command since it is not installed in the production servers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the CPU spike only if its longer than 5 minutes (which is usual interval for run `sar`. Shorter spike will not be recorded except when the spike happen on the time `sar` run (which is with quite low probability).

`htop`, `top` can't help you because they are interactive tools.

`atop` can be run as service, but (even if you have it installed) it must be run beforehand.

Comment: Atop definitely can be configured as a service to log system data on a regular basis. I've used it in the past on embedded systems to leave it running and come back to find out what commands are using CPU and disk at a later time. It is not solely an interactive "what is happening now" tool. `atop -w /path/to/logfile` will leave a program running in the background outputting a log for later analysis. https://linuxblog.io/atop-linux-server-performance-analysis/

Comment: @Romeo Ninov, can you please tell me what is the better way to find the cpu usage for the past 2 days in linux.

Comment: @Sameer, as I try to explain in my answer you have only `sar` data and as it run every 5 minutes you can get only average values of load. I am not familiar with `atop` but it seems promising.